# How to create unique string containing numbers and letters without repeating name once used

Tags: c#, random

I'm attempting the following coding challenge in C#:

> Manage robot factory settings.
>
> When a robot comes off the factory floor, it has no name.
>
> The first time you turn on a robot, a random name is generated in the
> format of two uppercase letters followed by three digits, such as
> RX837 or BC811.
>
> Every once in a while we need to reset a robot to its factory
> settings, which means that its name gets wiped. The next time you ask,
> that robot will respond with a new random name.
>
> The names must be random: they should not follow a predictable
> sequence. Using random names means a risk of collisions. Your solution
> must ensure that every existing robot has a unique name.

I've created a Robot class which passes 7 of my 8 unit tests. The one failing is:

```
[Fact]
public void Robot_names_are_unique()
{
    const int robotsCount = 10_000;
    var robots = new List<Robot>(robotsCount); // Needed to keep a reference to the robots as IDs of recycled robots may be re-issued
    var names = new HashSet<string>(robotsCount);
    for (int i = 0; i < robotsCount; i++) {
        var robot = new Robot();
        robots.Add(robot);
        Assert.True(names.Add(robot.Name));
        Assert.Matches(@"^[A-Z]{2}\d{3}$", robot.Name);
    }
}
```

I walked through my code and I believe the issue is because I'm generating random values but I'm not ensuring the values are unique when creating many names. Here's my class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

public class Robot
{
    Random random = new Random();
    Dictionary<string, bool> usedNames = new Dictionary<string, bool>();
    public Robot()
    {
        Name = RandomName();
    }

    private string _name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }


    public void Reset()
    {
        Name = RandomName();
    }

    private string RandomName()
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int nums = random.Next(000, 1000);
        var val = nums.ToString("000");
        const string chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        string letters = new string(Enumerable.Repeat(chars, 2)
            .Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)]).ToArray());
        string name = $"{letters}{val}";
        if (usedNames.ContainsKey(name))
        {
// Implement here or refactor with loop?
        }
        return name;
    }
}
```

However, after reviewing my code, I feel like there is a better approach. I was thinking the approach would involve iterating through the possible numbers and letters in the name sequentially from start to finish to ensure that each name is unique. Am I on the right track? What could I do better?

Comment: Is it possible to add an ID behind the random text?

Comment: `usedNames` is an instance field, so each `Robot` tracks their one used name, and that's it.

Comment: 1) You should use only one (static) instance of `Random` (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/767999/8967612)). 2) You're currently doing nothing to prevent generating duplicate names because a) `usedNames` is not shared across other instances and b) even if it were, your `if` statement is currently empty (or did you not include that part?).

Comment: I'd create a static `NameGenerator` class that tracks used names and generates new, unique names, and call its `CreateName()` method in your `Robot` class.

Comment: @41686d6564, I haven't implemented it yet. I wanted to see if it made more sense to rewrite this entire method to iterate through each possible value based on the total range of possible values... if that makes sense.+

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have only

```
26 * 26 * 1000 == 676000
```

possible names. Let's generate them *all* and *shuffle*. Then we can take next robot name from `names` one after one:

```
// Yates algorithm will be faster then ordering by random (here I've used Guid)
static string[] Names = Enumerable
  .Range(0, 26 * 26)
  .SelectMany(letters => Enumerable
     .Range(0, 1000)
     .Select(i => $"{(char)('A' + letters / 26)}{(char)('A' + letters % 26)}{i:000}"))
  .OrderBy(item => Guid.NewGuid())
  .ToArray();

static int currentIndex = -1;

// Interlocked: let's implement thread safe method 
static string NextName() => 
  Names[Interlocked.Increment(ref currentIndex) % Names.Length];
```

**Demo:**

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
  Console.WriteLine(NextName());
```

**Outcome:** (may vary from workstation to workstation)

```
JQ393
GQ249
JZ370
OC621
GD309
CP822
DK698
AD610
XY300
WV698
```

**Edit:** If we want to *reuse* names (which are dropped when robot is set to factory default settings) we can use `Queue` instead of array:

```
static ConcurrentQueue<string> Names = new ConcurrentQueue<string>(Enumerable
  .Range(0, 26 * 26)
  .SelectMany(letters => Enumerable
     .Range(0, 1000)
     .Select(i => $"{(char)('A' + letters / 26)}{(char)('A' + letters % 26)}{i:000}"))
  .OrderBy(item => Guid.NewGuid()));
  
static string NextName() => Names.TryDequeue(out string result) ? result : "???";

static string ScrapName(string name) => Names.Enqueue(name);

static string ResetName(string oldName) {
  string newName = Names.TryDequeue(out string result) 
    ? result 
    : "???";

  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(oldName))
    Names.Enqueue(oldName);

  return newName; 
}
```

Comment: The general idea is correct but modifications need to be made in order to support the factory reset thing mentioned in the question. Otherwise, duplicate names are still possible.

Comment: @Pharaz Fadaei: whenever we want a new name (either for new robot built or for factory reset) we just call `NextName()`. All (`626000`) names within `Names` are unique, so there will be no duplicates until we exhaust all `626000` of them

Comment: @PharazFadaei The next name index is static, it should always be pulling a new one from the list. It won't duplicate.

Comment: 1. All 676000 robots get their names. 2. The last robot resets (no 676000) 3. Next time the last robot looks for a name it will be given the name of the first robot (currentIndex + 1 % length will be 0) while the name at index 676000 - 1 is unused.

Comment: @Pharaz Fadaei: I see; when we reset robot to factory defaults we can take its name for the future *re-use*. In this scenario we can use `Queue` instead of array. Please, see my edit

Comment: Yes. The modified version takes care of the duplicity problems. But introduces randomness problems in my opinion. If I acquire names for all the robots and then reset them in order, I can predict exactly what name the next robot will get. I think some sort of priority queue (with Guids being the priority values) is preferable to handle both issues.

Comment: @defaultUsernameN that's a different thing. Randomness does not make sense when you only have a single option. If you reset two of them, the next name shouldn't be predictable.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to create a class to generate the names. That class should keep track of already created names. This method works better if the number of robots is not huge.

```
public class NameGenerator
{
    static HashSet<string> created = new HashSet<string>();
    static Random rand = new Random();
    const string chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    
    public static string GetName()
    {
        if (created.Count == 676000) {
            // Throw an exception?
        }

        string name;
        do {
            name = $"{chars[rand.Next(chars.Length)]}{chars[rand.Next(chars.Length)]}{rand.Next(0, 1000):D3}";
        } while (!created.Add(name));
        return name;
    }

    public static void Reset() {
        created = new HashSet<string>();
    }
}
```

Some quick profiling:

| Number of IDs generated | Time (s) | Time (ms) to create last | Approx. mem used (MB) } |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1,000 | ~0 | <1 | 0.05 |
| 10,000 | 0.005 | <1 | 0.52 |
| 50,000 | 0.032 | <1 | 2.4 |
| 100,000 | 0.078 | <1 | 4.9 |
| 250,000 | 0.229 | <1 | 11.1 |
| 500,000 | 0.626 | <1 | 22.8 |
| 600,000 | 0.961 | <1 | 25.1 |
| 625,000 | 1.143 | <1 | 25.8 |
| 650,000 | 1.390 | <1 | 26.3 |
| 676,000 | 5.386 | 293 | 38.5 |

Obviously there is a large increase once you approach the `676,000` limit.

Comment: That's going to get real slow at the end, when you check all 675999 names that you already created, until somehow you manage to land straight at the one you need... I am thinking minutes to hours =)

Comment: When we come to the end (say, all names but two or three are given) we'll have to do many tries (and fails) to obtain unused name. It can take much time (the process will be very slow)

Comment: Yes, I agree. If the number of robots is very large, then @DmitryBychenko's solution is better. A simple stopwatch test generated 500000 id's in 0.3788292 seconds.

Comment: I mean the problem is - the time to run .GetName() is as random as the name itself is. You might get a free name at first iteration, or not get it even on the billionth one. This function might take a millisecond, or it might take years.

Comment: @defaultUsernameN I think you are missing the advantage of this algorithm: if you only a have small number of robots - say a few hundred or thousands or even a few million - this algorithm _uses much less memory_ than creating every possible combination and choosing from that. Why create half a billion names when only a few thousand might be needed?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp that's fair, actually. I guess I got sidetracked by "the worst case for this algoritm means it runs for eternity" and didn't notice "that is perfectly fine for a lot of cases, and even if it does one day in the whole life of the universe hit that infinitesimal possibility of worst case, doubt it'll be piloting the Apollo at that moment". Thank you for explaining. I withdraw my case =)

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of possible names. Unless you plan on having almost half a million robots, a good solution would be to create a custom, reusable generator that keeps track of all generated names.

```
public class UniqueNameGenerator
{
   private readonly HashSet<string> generatedNames;
   private readonly Random generator;

   public UniqueNameGenerator(Random random = null)
   {
      this.generatedNames = new HashSet<string>();
      this.generator = random ?? new Random();
   }

   public string GenerateName()
   {
      string name;

      do
      {
          name = this.TryGenerateName();
      }
      while(this.generatedNames.Contains(name));

      this.generatedNames.Add(name);
      return name;
   }

   private string TryGenerateName()
   {
      var nameBuilder = new StringBuilder();

      nameBuilder.Append(this.PickRandomLetter('A', 'Z'));
      nameBuilder.Append(this.PickRandomLetter('A', 'Z'));
      nameBuilder.Append(this.PickRandomNumber(0, 1000));

      return nameBuilder.ToString();
   }

   private int PickRandomNumber(int min, int max)
   {
      return this.generator.Next(min, max + 1);
   }

   private char PickRandomLetter(char from, char to)
   {
      var letterIndex = this.generator.Next((int)from, (int)to);
      return (char)letterIndex;
   }
}
```

Keep a static instance of this inside the Robot class, or better, create a `RobotFactory` that creates robots with a single instance of the UniqueNameGenerator.

Answer (score -1):

use random.choice to select 2 random characters and 3 random numbers

```
import random

def generate_license():
    letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    numbers = "0123456789"
    license = ""
    for i in range(2):
        license += random.choice(letters)
    for i in range(3):
        license += random.choice(numbers)
    return license

for i in range(30):
    print(generate_license())
```

output:

FD508
FI820
TY975
NR415
GD041
IK313
GR103
WR994
PL631
WT808
UV119
KO727
LK584
GM629
BM545
VX728
UN773
AM000
UW267
KE949
KW182
TL030
YW536
AF038
PQ493
TT153
NP626
JK151
WA536
OU825

Comment: you check the old license with the new license and repeat the function if not unique.  otherwise use a guid to get an unique number.   c# can be easily mapped to python.

Comment: str(uuid.uuid4()) will create a guid and it will be more than 5 characters in length